# Pgfplots: Add curly rotated braces to a graph

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I created a simple graph of a demand function so far. Is there an easy way of addition curly rotated braces and labels to the graph (like in my sketch). Those should mark the intervals for a value epsilon smaller or greater than 1.

I had no idea so far, and the graph being nonlinear obviously does not make the task more easy.

```
\documentclass[13pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}                      
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=-0.5,xmax=4.9,ymin=-20,ymax=220,
    extra x ticks={2.66},
        extra x tick labels={$2.66\rightarrow$},
        extra x tick style={ticklabel style={rotate=35,yshift=-5pt,anchor=east,inner xsep=2pt}},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$p$,
        extra y ticks={115.470053838},
    tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
        ]
        \addplot+[no marks,blue,domain=0:4.1,samples=200, thick] {100* sqrt(4-x)};
    \filldraw (2.66,115.470053838) circle (2pt)node[right,font=\tiny] {unit elastic: $\epsilon = 1$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can draw curly braces by using `decorations`. I shifted the `ylabel` on the y axis by `1mm` because it was right in the middle of the brace, and did a similar thing to the node in the middle of the plot.

I also changed the font size to `12pt` because my editor was complaining, so you should change it back, but the drawing should be the same.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}                      
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=-0.5,xmax=4.9,ymin=-20,ymax=220,
    extra x ticks={2.66},
        extra x tick labels={$2.66\rightarrow$},
        extra x tick style={ticklabel style={rotate=35,yshift=-5pt,anchor=east,inner xsep=2pt}},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$p$,
    ylabel style={yshift=1mm},
        extra y ticks={115.470053838},
    tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
        ]
        \addplot+[no marks,blue,domain=0:4.1,samples=200, thick] {100* sqrt(4-x)};
    \filldraw (2.66,115.470053838) circle (2pt)node[above right,font=\tiny] {unit elastic: $\epsilon = 1$};

    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=15pt,raise=1pt,mirror}] (2.66,115.470053838) -- (0,200) 
            node [midway, xshift=-1mm, auto, swap, outer sep=10pt,font=\tiny]{$e < 1$};
    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=20pt,raise=2pt,mirror}] (4,2) -- (2.66,115.470053838) 
            node [midway, xshift=3mm, yshift=-1mm,auto, swap, outer sep=10pt,font=\tiny]{$e > 1$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```